# Append binary data to file

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

in my iPhone application I need to append binary data to file:

```
 NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:readBytes_];    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile"];

    NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:appFile];
    [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [myHandle writeData: data];
    [myHandle closeFile];
   // [data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];

    // Show contents of Documents directory
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@",
          [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

But in NSlog i don't see that there is my file. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files does not exist then `[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:]` will return `nil` (see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFileHandle/fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath%3a)).

Therefore check that before attempting to open the file and create it if necessary:

```
NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileMan fileExistsAtPath:appFile])
{
    [fileMan createFileAtPath:appFile contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:appFile];
// etc.
```

And add more error-checking all round.